# Почему среда программирования (IDE) не встроена в самом языке программирования?

Tags: python, ide

Собственно сам вопрос в заголовке, если это возможно, то я бы хотел попросить Вас изъяснить это как можно проще, ибо я новичок и только начинаю изучать Python.

Comment: Под *"..встроенна в самом языке.."*  вы имели ввиду "построена на самом языке" или (*только не это*) — "встроена в сам язык"?

Comment: Поясню на примере. Я скачал Python и для того чтобы программировать мне надо скачать еще и среду для этого(Wing IDE в данном случае). Почему нельзя скачать Python и реализовывать все вещи на нем?

Comment: Эмъ... Ну фильмы вы же не с компом или плеером покупаете ) Купили фильм, посмотрели на компе, потом на DVD, потому в гостях у кого-нить.

Так же и здесь - IDE всяких разных куча - какую использовать как дефолтную? Одним одно нравится, другим - другое.

Я, вот, вообще в npp пишу (это блокнот навороченный).

IDE - это удобная обертка для языка. А какую обертку использовать - решать уже вам.

Тот же C - компиляторов куча же, а что тогда про IDE говорить?

Comment: > Почему нельзя скачать Python и реализовывать все вещи на нем?

@Hashirama, можно. ``Python``, насколько я понял, вы уже скачали. Переходите к следующему шагу :)

Вот вам: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIDA
А вот еще лучше: http://ninja-ide.org/

Comment: Раз можно, то зачем тогда нужны IDE? =)

Comment: @Hashirama, у вас наблюдается логическая несостыковка. Если человек с помощью робота(I) будет собирать другого робота, то зачем первый робот?

*У меня такое ощущение, что я кормлю тролля..*

Comment: Т.е. можно скачать Python и реализовывать на нем все вещи, однако существуют IDE "используемые программистами для разработки программного обеспечения."(из вики). Вопрос: зачем существуют тогда IDE нужны, если все вещи реализуемые в IDE можно реализовать в Python? 
P.s. нет я не тролль, просто полный 0 в программировании(

Comment: "IDE встроенная в язык программирования" - это бессмыслица. Точно так же, ка например, соковыжималка, встроенная в яблоко. IDE - это инструмент, очень сильно облегчающий программирование и берущий на себя множество рутинных действий. Теоретически вы можете программировать и без IDE, но это неудобно. "Встраивать" ее в язык бессмысленно, это разные сущности, хоть и связанные друг с другом. Язык - это некий (абстрактный) набор правил (не стоит путать сам язык и средства, его реализующие - компиляторы, интерпретаторы, библиотеки и прочее)), а IDE - это (конкретный) программный инструмент

Comment: @Hashirama, IDE не расширяют язык. Они облегчают вам работу. Это как молоток - при желании вы гвоздь и кулаком вбить сможете, но будет тяжело.

Откройте скрипт ``Блокнотом`` и каким-нибудь ``PyCharm'ом`` - сравните ощущения.

Comment: >Вопрос: зачем существуют тогда IDE нужны, если все вещи реализуемые в IDE можно реализовать в Python?

а зачем существуют автомобили, если из пункта А в пункт Б можно добраться пешком? Ответ очевиден - автомобиль удобнее, быстрее, безопасне, надежнее, etc. То же самое с IDE

Comment: @Hashirama, я же написал - IDE - это удобная обертка для языка.

Рефакторинг, подсветка синтаксиса, возможность запуска программы из IDE и ее отладка, подсказка по функциям-классам (в том числе по пользовательским, если они прокомментированы как следует), автоматическая проверка синтаксиса и т.д. - перечислять можно долго.

В одних IDE удобно одно, в других - другое, кому что больше нравится. Вот мне не нравится - мне IDE и не нужны.

Использовать или нет - решать вам, но, в любом случае, стоит хотя бы разок посмотреть что та или иная IDE из себя представляет. А там глядишь - и понравится )

Comment: ВОРОН, DreamChild большое Вам спасибо!
Я все понял.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть сам язык программирования, это просто текст, который вы можете писать хоть на бумаге, хоть на заборе.

Есть интерпретатор, который вы и скачали. Вы передаете ему текст языка Python в командной строке и он запускает программу. Текст вы можете писать где угодно, даже в простом блокноте и потом скормить его интерпретатору, запустив программу.

IDE - это набор инструментов для упрощения разработки. Подсвечивает слова, завершает фразы, выдает подсказки, выдает удобное дерево каталогов с файлами, одной кнопкой сама скармливает текст интерпретатору, подсказывает где ошибки и многое другое в зависимости от функциональности. Их много разновидностей(WingIDE, Aptana, Eclipse, Scite и т.д.), но IDE не обязательна, достаточно блокнота и компилятора.

Comment: Большое спасибо, теперь все понял.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас Windows (а скорее всего, это так), то в python там встроена IDLE, и не нужно ничего качать. И вообще, программы можно в блокноте писать.

Ну а если хотите каких-то плюшек (автодополнение, проверка ошибок и т. п.), то придётся скачать и среду разработки. Ту, которая вам больше по душе.

Comment: IDLE в стандартной библиотеке присутствует. Её нет на некоторых дистрибутивах Linux по умолчанию только если они специально её выпилили (например, если X-ов нет, то нет смысла графические вещи тащить). `python3 -midlelib` запускает IDLE на моей не Windows машине.